# Is it possible to use getElementByClassName() on element that was created by javascript - Mapbox

Tags: javascript, php, mapbox

Is it possible to use getElementByClassName() to obtain an element that was created by javascript?

Im trying to get the distance from Mapbox (Just using pure js). See the picture =>
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me0N3.png)

Im trying to obtain that h1 element. See the picture =>
[H1 Value that created by mapbox javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqpVj.png)

My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
var code = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[2].innerHTML;
document.getElementById("km").value = code; } </script>
```

Im trying to get the h1 element's contents with the method above, but it didn't work.

Any solution?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular thankyou. No worries, im not gonna mad. Cause someone already answer my question and its helped me to solve my code. And it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the h1 that is a child of the element with classname `mapbox-directions-component` you can use `getElementsByClassName` and then chain a `getElementsByTagName` from that dom location. Note that both selectors return a collection of elements. So if you know it's the first element with that class and first tag that is a child of that element you can use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mapbox-directions-component")[0].getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML
```

However a more direct approach, in my opinion, would be to use `querySelector`: [MDN Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
document.querySelector(".mapbox-directions-component h1").innerHTML
```

Comment: OMG, thats helped me! Thankyou so much! I've tried querySelector() and its work. Thankyou. !!